# My form is not displaying fields and I cant figure out why

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am creating a contact form in django to send an email but the form is not displaying on the webpage. I think the issue may be because the form object may have never been passed to the context correctly, but I have no idea where it is going wrong. The code below is what I have so far.

```
from .forms import *
```

**My Views**

```
def email(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(first_name + ": " + subject, message, email,
                          ['flavioandersites@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse("Invalid Header.")
            return redirect('thankyou')
    return render(request, 'Index-App/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

**My Form Class**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**Urls**

```
url(r'^contact/$', views.email, name='contact'),
```

**My Template**

```
{% block contact %}
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'Index-App:contact' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Send"/>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I made a mistake, the second Contact should have been ContactForm()

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not instantiating your form when method is `GET`. Also, you need to change `self` param to `request`

Try the following:

```
def email(request):  # pass request for your view param, not self
    form = ContactForm()  # You should instantiate your form for GET method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        # ...
    return render(request, 'Index-App/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: @melb27 instead of `email(self)` use `email(request)`. Which error are you getting exactly?

Comment: The forms fields are not displaying. The fields to enter email and such. it just shows the send button. Is there another way to make a form to send a contact email you can show me? I have actually been going at this for a few days now.

Comment: I can not see any other issue with your above code, it should work without problem.

Comment: It is not work at all, the form send but no fields are displayed.

Comment: Thank, It worked. Turns out the templates were being rendered in a way that the form would not show. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ettanany I think the default handling is `GET` so the form will be instantiated isn't it

Comment: @Bobby You're right, OP did not include `form = ContactForm()` before `if request.method == 'POST'` at the beginning.